# C# performance cost of exceptions

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, exception

I'm building a project where the config file will be load as a dictionary. To prevent from invalid config, I simply added an try catch frame. But I noticed that when exceptions throw, there will be a dramatic performance dropping. So I made a test:

```
var temp = new Dictionary<string, string> {["hello"] = "world"};
var tempj = new JObject() {["hello"]="world"};
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     try
     {
        var value = temp["error"];
     }
     catch
     {
          // ignored
     }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time cost on Exception:"+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds +"ms");
sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   var value = tempj["error"];   //equivalent to value=null
}
Console.WriteLine("Time cost without Exception:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
Console.ReadLine();
```

And the result is:

> Time cost on Exception:1789ms
>
> Time cost without Exception:0ms

The *JObject* here is taken from *Newtownsoft.Json*, which does not throw an exception when no key is found ,as opposed to *Dictionary*.

So my question is:

1. Does exception throwing really slow down the program that much?
2. How do I guarantee the performance when multiple exceptions may occur?
3. Anyway work around if I really want to use *Dictionary* in this case?(shut down the KeyNotFoundException?)

Thank you!

Comment: Exception **throwing** does not slow down your program, but **catching** will do

Comment: Workaround - use `TryGetValue` method of dictionary which do not throw exception when key not found - it simply will return `false`. If key is there, then it will return `true` and set the value of `out` parameter which you are passing

Comment: If you're going to measure performance, don't run your code under a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to avoid exceptions in your example code at all. The most expensive part is the `try .. catch`.

If you cannot get away from exceptions then you should use a different pattern to perform actions inside a loop.

Instead of

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    try
    {
        DoSomethingThatMaybeThrowException();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // igrnore or handle
    }
```

which will set up the `try .. catch` for every step whether an exception has raised or not, use

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < 100 )
    try
    {
        while( i < 100 )
        {
            DoSomethingThatMaybeThrowException();
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        // ignore or handle
        i++;
    }
```

which will only set up a new `try .. catch` when an exception was thrown.

**BTW**

I cannot reproduce that massive slowdown of your code as you describe. [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LYASZB)

Comment: Thanks,you are right.But I suppose you don't need to divide the sum12 by 100.0 for milliseconds output.

Comment: And if there is no Exception, "ForTry" and "TryFor" give me the same performance. Does this mean the cost is due to throw-catch while try-catch setup dose no effect(somehow optimized by compiler)?https://dotnetfiddle.net/tTaxzG

Comment: @joe if I want to get the average time for each call I had to divide the whole time for 100 calls by 100 to get it for one

Comment: Um...I see, I made it total time in my code.